# What are PowerShell Task credentials used for?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

TFS 2015 Update 2 is my first exposure to what used to be the standalone Release Management tools.

I'm trying to do a deploy to a host, and part of that is applying DSC. It appears that the way to do this is to use a PowerShell task. The Machines field is obvious enough, but the login credentials are ambiguous. Are those credentials simply used to authorize RM to run the script against the target and I need to embed other credentials as necessary? Or is the script run *as* that user and the script should be able to do things like get to the drop folder if the user has the right permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the task uses WinRM to run scripts on target machines. So the scripts will be run on target machines under the given user.

Quoting text from the [Task's GitHub Page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachines)

**Machines:** Specify comma separated list of machine FQDNs/ip addresses along with port(optional). For example dbserver.fabrikam.com, dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986,192.168.34:5986. Port when not specified will be defaulted to WinRM defaults based on the specified protocol. i.e., (For WinRM 2.0): The default HTTP port is 5985, and the default HTTPS port is 5986. Machines field also accepts 'Machine Groups' defined under 'Test' hub, 'Machines' tab.

**Admin Login:** Domain/Local administrator of the target host. Format: \ < Admin User>. Mandatory when used with list of machines, optional for Test Machine Group (will override test machine group value when specified).

**Password:** Password for the admin login. It can accept variable defined in Build/Release definitions as '$(passwordVariable)'. You may mark variable type as 'secret' to secure it. Mandatory when used with list of machines, optional for Test Machine Group (will override test machine group value when specified).

For reference: [VSTS Release Management Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/overview)

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. In the previous version of RM, using DSC meant not needing an agent, but this seems to indicate that an agent is needed with the current version. What's the right way of looking at it?

Comment: Yes you are right. The current version  of RM requires VSTS agent which then connects to target machines using WinRM. This is particularly helpful if the RM server cannot directly access the target machines.

Comment: So now first RM tells agent to run the powershell task as part of a release. The task running on the agent will then connect to target machines using WinRM and so it's magic.

Comment: So, we still don't need an agent on the target machine (in this case the web server)?

Comment: You are right, you dont need agent on the web server. The agent could be hosted if you are using VSTS or it could be sitting on one of your machines. The only requirement is that the agent should be able to access web server.

Comment: Is there some documentation that mentions this? I'd like to review it to make sure I'm not missing anything else.

Comment: Search for the new VSTS RM blog posts. I will post the link once I am back to desktop

Comment: @ketch I have edited the answer with the link to new RM docs.